# How do I create a surface plot in matplotlib when Z is already calculated?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have seen the following example for surface plot [here, in the Surface Plot section](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html):

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Make data.
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)

# Plot the surface.
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

# Customize the z axis.
ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

# Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

In the example, X and Y coordinates are provided as vectors, to later be reused as a XY coordinate mesh with the mesh command.

In the example, Z is calculated directly from X,Y. However in my case I am using a previously calculated value for Z (so somehow I already did the mesh function in previous steps):

```py
array([[1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+01, 1.59135708e+06],
       [1.00000000e+00, 1.10000000e+01, 2.44938222e+06],
       [1.00000000e+00, 1.20000000e+01, 3.96364528e+06],
       [1.00000000e+00, 1.30000000e+01, 6.13414627e+06],
       [1.00000000e+00, 1.40000000e+01, 8.96088517e+06],
       [2.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+01, 1.59386643e+06],
       [2.00000000e+00, 1.10000000e+01, 2.45962860e+06],
       [2.00000000e+00, 1.20000000e+01, 3.98162868e+06],
       [2.00000000e+00, 1.30000000e+01, 6.15986668e+06],
       [2.00000000e+00, 1.40000000e+01, 8.99434261e+06],
       [3.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+01, 1.59647579e+06],
       [3.00000000e+00, 1.10000000e+01, 2.46997497e+06],
       [3.00000000e+00, 1.20000000e+01, 3.99971208e+06],
       [3.00000000e+00, 1.30000000e+01, 6.18568710e+06],
       [3.00000000e+00, 1.40000000e+01, 9.02790005e+06],
       [4.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+01, 1.59918515e+06],
       [4.00000000e+00, 1.10000000e+01, 2.48042135e+06],
       [4.00000000e+00, 1.20000000e+01, 4.01789548e+06],
       [4.00000000e+00, 1.30000000e+01, 6.21160752e+06],
       [4.00000000e+00, 1.40000000e+01, 9.06155749e+06]])
```

So the first column is the X, the second the Y and the third one the Z.

Z comes from R which is calculated using `np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)` and `X`, `Y` are already variables created with mesh.

How shall those values be assigned to variables `X`, `Y` and `Z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have an aray `arr`. Then you can cast it to the format expected by matplotlib as:

```
# Make data.
X = arr[:,0].reshape((4,5)).T
Y = arr[:,1].reshape((4,5)).T
Z = arr[:,2].reshape((4,5)).T
```

and plot:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
# Plot the surface.
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

# Customize the z axis.
# ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)
# ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.1E'))

# Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=.7, aspect=5, pad=.1);
```

[image]

You also may wish to generelaize like:

```
from itertools import groupby
total_length = arr.shape[0]
group_length = [len(list(g)) for _,g in groupby(arr[:,0])]
print(f"Reshape 1st: {int(total_length/group_length[0])}",f"Reshape 2nd: {int(group_length[0])}",sep="\n")
Reshape 1st: 4 
Reshape 2nd: 5
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey, why are you using specifically 4 and 5 (`.reshape(4,5)`)?

Comment: This is because how your array is structured, 4 groups of 5 points